# Can't display an image (Win7 x64 Opencv 2.3)

Tags: opencv

```
 #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

    int main()
    {
        cv::Mat im =cv::imread("C:/OpenCV2.3/opencv/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images/query.png");
        if(im.empty())
        {
            return -1;
        }

        cv::namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cv::imshow("image" , im);
        cv::waitKey();
        return 0;
    }
```

After executing this code sample , i have gray window. Whean i move a cursor on the window, it shows , that something is loading. What's the problem? I'am sure that the imagepath is correct.

Comment: I haven't had any luck with the C++ interface on Windows at all using OpenCV 2.3. The C interface works like a charm, though.

Comment: Your code works for me. (Both x86 and x64 build on Windows 7 x64)

Comment: Are you using Visual studio or some other IDE? I had similar issues with OpenCV 2.2 and eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Turned out my system missed the `msvcp100d.dll` and `msvcr100d.dll` files.